# Why people rotate during flight in Rocket League?

Tags: rocket-league

Why high level people on Rocket League rotate with their cars while they are flying? Do they fly faster or higher or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your speed is identical, but spinning gives you the potential to:

- make slightly harder hits by using torque to add power the car's contact with the ball (this is the reason that flips result in harder hits than simply driving at a ball),
- make the resulting hit a bit tougher for the opponent to read, as the direction of your spin combined with your boost allows slight adjustments in midair,
- practice better midair car control since even a live match is still an opportunity to improve your skills, and/or
- make the resulting replay just a bit flashier, as spinning doesn't make the car any harder to control when you're used to it.

Comment: _"this is the reason that flips result in harder hits"_ - Actually the main reason is that flips do increase your forward-momentum as well

Comment: So when you are flying you look Where is the car respect to the ball and you press the second jump to give it a little more power?

Comment: @IlJoker11 In a long aerial, you generally want to use your second jump immediately to gain momentum in your aerial without wasting more boost than you have to.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Koviko mentioned, another reason is for better control.  During eg. a tornado spin, as the bottom of your car spins quickly from pointing to the lower-left to the lower-right and back again, you can make micro-adjustments to adjust your car's path in the air much more quickly than you could if you only rotated your car along a single axis.

Comment: This answer is the first time this was explained well to me.  Instead of having to think about the adjustments needed on two axes (and two controls), you can constantly spin one and focus your adjustments on a single control.  Helpful answer thanks!

Comment: When you say micro-adjustments, are you referring to steering inputs, or timing bursts of boost to match up with different car alignments?